# installed JDK 7 is not found in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I run eclipse helios (64 bit version) on windows 7 (64 bit) platform. I've downloaded both JDK 6 and 7 on "Program Files" folder. I want to compile my Java program in Java 1.7 so that I'd following to switch it.

1. click on project folder
2. select Properties
3. select Java Compiler

However system doesn't show Java 1.7 option.

[update]

after adding jdk 1.7 under installed JREs.

[image]

Comment: is your JDK 64-bit version? If not, install 64-bit version.

Comment: @Rafael: Thanks for your reply. I just verified that downloaded JDK 7 is 64 bit. I ran "java -version" and I got "Java HotSport<TM> 64-Bit Server VM..."

Comment: Check @Javy's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need config eclipse `jdk`, add the `jdk 1.7` to eclipse, the following screenshot is below

click `Windows->Prefrence`

[image]

then click `Add...`

[image]

then `next`

[image]

select the `jre` directory, then click finish button, you will find the `jdk7`choice

Comment: Thanks! I added jdk 1.7 under Installed JREs (initially it had jre6)  and restarted eclipse, however the problem is still persistent. I see Java 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6 at compiler compliance level. very strange...

Comment: @DaeYoung likely your project has its own configured Java 6 runtime then that overrules the workspace default. Check the "java build path" of the project and then the "libraries" tab. What do you see there?

Comment: @Gimby: That was it. Thank you for guiding me to a right direction. Now I look back it was so obvious.

Comment: @Gimby: Will do. Thanks.